# How to sort array preserving its initial state

Tags: php, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.0 here. The title is a bit misleading, so to clear things up - I have session array which is populated with ids of products as user adds them to cart. So this array goes like [0] => 25, [1] => 70 etc. Let's say this array is called $products.

What I want to ask is is there some possibility  to have array which I get by using 'find' model's function ('conditions' => array('Product.id' => $products)) to be sorted not by some of Model.field values (as in 'order' option), but by $products array indices, so that when I render the products content in view I would get all those products in cart sorted in such sequence as user were adding them.

Here's an example - 
Session array $products:

```
[0] => 35,
[1] => 15,
[2] => 25
```

Then I pass this array to conditions of find function:

```
$list = $this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Product.id' => $products)));
```

In the end $list gives me array which sorted by product.id. So instead of having:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 35 )),
[1] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15 )),

[2] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25 ))
```

I get:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15 )),
[1] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25 )),
[2] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 35 ))
```

So far all the answers doesn't solve my problem. Please, pay closer attention to the example I gave, it's very simple, but the answers provided are in different key.

Again, I need final array **$list** to be sorted by indices of session array **$products**, but I get **$list** sorted by Product.id field, even though I didn't specify any `'find(array('order'=> ...))'` at all and even tried to set it to false.

Comment: cannot understand the question but i guess this may help...you cannot sort an array preserving its initial state (because your ordering it), but you could store it twice or even better you could store store the array's indexes at its initial state, so you can order the array as you had in your initial state (or viceversa) whenever you want. $initial_state_indexes = array_keys($the_array);

Comment: Agree, question is a bit vague... Try clarifying your point with code or coming at it from a different angle

Comment: I'm not using 'order' at all. As I said, session array $products contains ids of products in which indices (from [0] and so on) represent sequence of products added by user.

Comment: I'm not sure why you brought up 'order', no one else mentioned it. "(as in 'order' option)", "so that when I render the order contents".

Comment: Still unsure what the problem is. You say you want to render the array in the order the customer added them, but the array is already in that order and Freida Kila gave you the solution for saving its initial state. If you want more help I'd suggest updating your question so it is more clear what you are trying to accomplish. The best way to do this is by adding code of what you have already tried, or examples of what the array currently looks like and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437076/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-other-array) I think it accomplishes what you want.

Comment: **showerhead** said "You say you want to render the array in the order the customer added them, but the array is already in that order" - no it's not in that order. Can you please pay a little more attenition? It's _supposed_ to be in that order, but in the end I get array which is sorted by Product.id even though I didn't specify any 'order' in find options at all.

Comment: I was paying attention, as I said, your original post was very vague. I was responding as I saw it to illustrate just how vague I found it. Now that you have added the changes I suggested you have gotten 4 answers and my last comment as potential solutions, more than you would have otherwise. There is no need to be rude. Have you tried any of the offered solutions yet or are you just going back to argue a moot point?

Comment: I really wasn't rude or anything, just that solutions provided were not suitable and judging them I'd really say people who gave answers hadn't paid close attention to the question. Sorry if I sounded rude, I didn't want to be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to sound rude, but all of responses to my question were about how to order my array by Product id (which was clearly not what I asked) or suggestions on doing manual sql queries which is inappropriate. Seems like I couldn't properly describe what I needed, but I tried to make it as clear as possible, sorry.

I stumbled upon a solution while trying to find how to 'disable order' in cake. So basically what you need to do is to have an array (let's call it **$queue**) where you keep product ids as they are added to cart, and then in 'order' option in find model function (or paginate) you should provide it like:

```
'order'=>array('FIELD(Product.id,'.implode(',', $queue).')')
```

**$queue** might look like this, as example:

```
[queue] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 11
        )
```

In the end you get **$list** array in which the order of products is same as in **$queue**. If you didn't specify 'order' then you would get you **$list** array like this:

```
 [queue] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 11
                [2] => 51
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simple SQL query that would order the results according to a list of parameters.

So the simplest is probably to reorder the records after having fetched them from the db.

```
$records = $this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Product.id' => $products)));

$sorted_records = array();
foreach($records as $record)
{
  $key = array_search($record['Product']['id'], $products);
  $sorted_records[$key] = $record;
}

ksort($sorted_records);

debug($sorted_records);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid SQL, not sure how to make cakephp render it but i think it will solve your ordering issue :

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (35, 15, 25) ORDER BY id = 35 DESC, id = 15 DESC, id = 25`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to order the model result, or in other words set an order on the query to sort in an arbitrary fashion.

Here's two options:

1. Specify a sort. Not familiar with Cake but the mysql you need to generate is: `order by id = 25 desc, id = 70 desc, id = etc` (a guess would say to try `order => 'id = 25 desc, id = 70 desc, id = etc'`) which you'd have to assemble from the `$products` array.
2. create a basket model and use a join query to get the product list in the correct order (not simple but probably better than relying on a session var).

**Update**

I had paid attention and did fix your issue providing you with the SQL you needed to generate, along with a guess at the Cake syntax. Looking at your posted solution, your FIELD(id, x, x, x) is doing the same thing, but is a much cleaner solution. Well done for finding it, I'd remove your "don't mean to be rude" comments though, as they generally do seem a *little* rude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cake or its database layers, but maybe you can add a little bit of sql.

The relevant sql would be something like

```
order by field(myTable.myID, 35, 15, 25)
-- or alternatively, more cross database compatible
order by case when myTable.myID = 35 then 1
              when myTable.myID = 15 then 2
              when myTable.myID = 25 then 3
         end
```

however, the most universal approach would be to just reorder in php code.

```
$products = array(35,15,25);//the ordered array
$records = array_flip($products);
foreach ($list as $row) {
    $id = $row['Product']['id'];
    $records[$id] = $row;
}
print_r($records);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually handle problems like this is by indexing the $list by the Product ID using the Set class, which is built into Cake. So

```
$list = Set::combine($list, '{n}.Product.id', '{n}.Product');
```

Then use loop through your cart ($products) which is already in the order you want

```
foreach($products as $prod) echo $list[$prod]['Product']['name'];
```

Hope this helps.