# php reorder array based on order of other array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => this is the newest post
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 70
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => sdfsfsdf
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 63
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => test
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 49
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Hello world!
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 1
    )
```

)

The ssm_featured_post_id value corresponds to the value of the array items in the second array.
I want to order the first array items in the same order as the items in the second array

```
Array
(
    [1] => 63
    [0] => 70
    [3] => 1
    [2] => 49
)
```

so the result after sorting would be

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (

        [title] => sdfsfsdf
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 63
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => this is the newest post
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 70
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Hello world!
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 1

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => test
        [ssm_featured_post_id] => 49
    )

)
```

Comment: Technically the second array isn't in the order you show in the output. The sequence that the values appear visually (63, 70, 1, 49) does not matter as the indices of the array (1, 0, 3, 2) are out of order. I expect this is merely a formatting error?

Comment: solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437076/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-other-array?rq=1

Comment: I found that other thread which answered my question and when I came back I saw all these acceptable answers. what do I do?

Comment: Accept one. They both solve your problem. Pick whichever you think applies more to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler way would be to use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and write a function that uses the second table to compare two values from first table.

Comment: That is a solution, whether it's "simpler" depends on the implementation. Valid answer though, voted.

Comment: Yeah maybe there is a simpler solution, but it seems to me that this would be the one I'd use

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), particularly the third example given. The idea is that you create arrays based on the "columns" of the multidimensional array, then sort them simultaneously, and put the result back in the original array.